# Debugging with helper / extension Method Regarding output of method its name and time of operation

Tags: c#, debugging, extension-methods

I am creating a "kind of" Extension method that will help me debug my future codes

there's a `Listview` "LV_MyAppLog" with columns

```
record # , MethodName, Method's OutPut, Time.
```

only that the time part i was unable to decide which is the simplest but non the less The professional way to implement.

this is the code i already built :

```
        public int LogCounter = 1;
        public void AHLog_AddRecord(string FunctionName = "N/A", string FunctionOutPut = "N/A")
        {

            ListViewItem MyItem= new ListViewItem();
            MyItem.Text = LogCounter.ToString();
            Lview_AutomationLog.Items.Insert(0, MyItem);
            MyItem.SubItems.Add(FunctionName);
            MyItem.SubItems.Add(FunctionOutPut);
            //place for the time SubItem(column)
            LogCounter++;

        }


        public void AddToAppLog()
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); 
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1); 
if(Completed)
            AHLog_AddRecord(sf.GetMethod().ToString().Replace("Void", ""), "Success")  ; 
else 
            AHLog_AddRecord(sf.GetMethod().ToString().Replace("Void", ""), "Fail")  ; 

        }
```

i wanted to add the time when a given method took place,

Am i supposed to do it with `DateTime now` Like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string theTime = now.ToString();// if so , What is the format to use to get only time h:m:s 
AHLog_AddRecord(sf.GetMethod().ToString().Replace("Void", ""), "Fail" , theTime)
```

or should i use a stop watch which i am not familiar with at all (: but i will be happy to learn it through this code example of mine , only if it's the better approach.

can i ask for the right syntax using the correct implementation within my `AddToAppLog()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datetime.Now.ToString() is ok, but I'd log the milliseconds too.

```
.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), if you want to measure a *range* of time, a *range* of execution.

In your case, instead, seems that you need just information about a time when execution happens.

Fill free to use a `DateTime.Now` in most suitable format.