# How to get method name for debug output in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, debugging, methods

I would like to make a macro that prints out the current method's name during Log.d and Log.e output.  Right now I simply type the method name within a hard-coded string, but this is obviously inefficient should the method name change in the future, as each string needs to be searched for and replaced.

I am aware of using getMethodName() as indicated in this post:

[How to get method name in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864175/how-to-get-the-name-of-method-in-current-class/3864230#3864230)

This one also looks promising:

[Debugging with helper extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155605/debugging-with-helper-extension-method-regarding-output-of-method-its-name-and)

There are countless numbers of these posts on SO, but I'd like to find the best way for debugging purposes that does not impact runtime performance too much.  Since I am using Eclipse I would like to find a solution that works well with that IDE.

Comment: are you an eclipse fanatic?

Comment: @pskink No.  Why do you ask?

Comment: because i wrote an eclipse plug-in that when you call: Log.d(TAG, "msg") you will see in the logcat as if you called: Log.d(TAG, "myMethod:142, msg")

Comment: I use Eclipse for all my Android work, so if you post that as an answer I can review your plug-in and possibly accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: the point is SO doesnt let me attach any files or i am wrong?

Comment: @pskink You can post your code inline using code-sample markup.

Comment: im not sure if its visible to others, but anyway plugin is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/cc6cdayrjfo71er/org.pskink.logger_1.0.0.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I know of that is available to you for the current execution.

```
    Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    StackTraceElement[] stack = current.getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement element : stack)
    {
        if (!element.isNativeMethod()) {
            String className = element.getClassName();
            String fileName = element.getFileName();
            int lineNumber = element.getLineNumber();
            String methodName = element.getMethodName();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll try that out.  Thanks.  Do you think that will have minimal impact on execution?  Is there a way to use conditional compilation (as in C/C++) whereby I can remove this stuff from production code via a simple flag?

Comment: I personally keep a class with those kind of runtime values (log levels, or turning logging off entirely, etc) and then run a unit test before compiling a production release to confirm all of my expected values.  And for performance, you can log the execution time of the method to see if it's really an issue.  I can't imagine it is unless you're running it on each iteration of a loop that is also updating the UI or something.  Sounds like you'll want to run all of your logging through a custom logging class, so that it's easy to turn this off with a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple yet very useful eclipse plug-in i mentioned in the comment above: [download plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cc6cdayrjfo71er/org.pskink.logger_1.0.0.jar)

its an incremental builder so typical build time is measured in fractions of seconds. add it to your .project file as a new builder `<buildCommand>` with name:

```
<name>org.pskink.logger.builder</name>
```

it should be the last builder in `<buildSpec>` list

installation: just copy it to `plugins` folder and restart eclipse