# calling methods details like line number, method name and class name in android

Tags: android

I need to display the calling methods details like line number, method name and class name.
How to get all those information in android,whenever a method is called in an application the calling method info has to be dispalyed,can anyone help me in solving this...

Comment: do u want to show that in your logcat or toast?

Comment: I want to show method info in toast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442747/getting-the-name-of-the-current-executing-method check this,

Answer (score 1):

You can get  using the following code- [copied from [How to get method name for debug output in Android/Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074073/how-to-get-method-name-for-debug-output-in-android-java#17075123) ]

```
 Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    StackTraceElement[] stack = current.getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement element : stack)
    {
        if (!element.isNativeMethod()) {
            String className = element.getClassName();
            String fileName = element.getFileName();
            int lineNumber = element.getLineNumber();
            String methodName = element.getMethodName();
        }
    }
```

Once you got the line number, method name, class name you can use it as you wish.